# I have a propane-fired forced air heating system. Is there any reason why I shouldn't install a humidifier in the air duct?

Tags: furnace, humidifier

"A friend" said that installing a whole-house humidifier in the forced air ducts of a propane-fired was no-no. I'm imagining that the humidifier can't tell whether the passing air is heated by natural gas, furnace oil or propane.
Am I missing something?

Comment: nothing to do with heating type

Comment: You're right, in fact if it can tell, you need to be red tagged :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason not to use humidifier inside duct system would be the dust.

Moist dust will stick to the walls and will be more difficult to remove during maintenance cycle.

This effect has nothing to do with heat source type.